# mySql in Xampp doesn't let me start the mysqld from command line

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am a beginner in MySQL and I have a problem with starting the server.
I have `xampp` installed and Happen the following:
If I start MySQL server from `xampp` control panel it runs, but if I try to start it from command line it remain in standby at a certain point and doesn't run.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL binaries should be somewhere under your XAMPP folder. Look for a /bin folder, and you'll find the mysql.exe client around. Let's assume it is in c:\xampp\mysql\bin, then you should fireup a command prompt in this folder.

That means, fire up "cmd", and type:

```
cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql.exe -u root --password
```

If you want to use mysqldump.exe, you should also find it there.

Log into your mysql server, and start typing your commands.

On the Mac, or at least on my Mac using a default install, I accessed it at:

```
/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -uroot -p
```

For Linux:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -uroot -p
```

and i am hoping you have already added environmental variable

Comment: I done this.I correct the issue. Now I saw that when i run the mysqld.exe from command line it actually starts, but it remain with the blinking cursor and not let me do any command in the cmd.